# Bug: stats.probplot returns as text inside the plot R not R^2 as it says

Tags: python, scipy, python-2.x

Inside the Figure is written as R^2 but as it is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html) it corresponds to the r_value or squared root of the coefficient of determination. To verify it I used **stats.linregress**.

```
stats.probplot(df_residual['residual'].values, dist="norm",plot=plt)
```

[image: Normal plot]

```
osm,osr=stats.probplot(df_residual['residual'].values, dist="norm")
x=osm[0];y=osm[1]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
print r_value, r_value**2
0.978054218803 0.956590054918
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not familiar with SciPy, but this appears to be a bug. Perhaps you should submit a bug report.

Comment: Thanks @TylerCrompton, where can I submit it?

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues - this is the official issue tracker at github

Comment: This was fixed in Oct. 2014 (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4097).  Which version of scipy are you using?  (Run `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.)

Comment: Thank you Warren you are right. I´m using version 0.14.0. That must be the reason, if it was fixed.

Comment: Looks like the fix is in 0.15.